# How can i implement real time notifications in django?

Tags: django, django-notification

I have read many blogs regarding this but could not understand. Can someone help me in this like what are the different ways of doing it and how to implements this.

Comment: One option would be to create a `Notifications` model to store notifications each time an action is completed. Then on the UI, create an ajax function that searches/displays new notifications every 'X' seconds.

Answer (score 0):

For real-time updates on your website / webapp, you will need to use something like Websockets or Server Sent Events. You can use a package to implement it yourself (in this case one approach is using [django-channels](https://github.com/django/channels/)) or use an external service that can deal with all the infrastructural complexity for you, such as [Pusher](https://pusher.com/), [Ably](https://www.ably.io/) or many others (a more comprehensive list can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-alternatives-to-pusher-com)).

Choosing one or another approach depends on your needs and requirements and how to implement this depends on the approach you have chosen.

You can see a description of how to implement a similar feature with django channels [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/getting-started-with-django-channels/). And how to do it using pusher [here](https://blog.pusher.com/django-pusherable/).